# Mongoose ObjectId not matched in typescript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I defined an interface using mongoose.

```
import {Types} from 'mongoose'    

export interface IShop {  
  readonly center: Types.ObjectId;    
}


async create(data):Promise<IShop>{
   const result = await new this.model(data).save
   return result
}
```

And there is a shcema as below.

```
 {
   center: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
 }
```

But this gives an error of type saying

> Error:(18, 5) TS2322:
> Types of property 'center' are incompatible.
> Type 'ObjectId' is missing the following properties from type 'ObjectId': generationTime, equals, getTimestamp, toHexString

But when I define `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` in interface it matches well. But I have to use `Types.ObjectId` for making `new Types.ObjectId(string)` in somewhere.

Could you help me some advice for this?

I use mongoose 5.11.9 and I dont' use `@types/mongoose`.

Comment: You found anything? getting the same issue